# Multiplication in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

I am trying to make a simple MACC to work, but it does unexpected things.
The multiplication is not working. 00001 * 00001 outputs 00000

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity macc is
    Port ( clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
           rst : in  STD_LOGIC;
           en : in  STD_LOGIC;
           A : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);
           B : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);
           P : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (8 downto 0));
end macc;

architecture Behavioral of macc is
    signal product : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (8 downto 0);
    signal acc_in : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (8 downto 0);
    signal acc_out : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (8 downto 0);
begin

    product <= A*B;
    acc_in <= acc_out + product;

        acc: process is
        begin
        wait until rising_edge(clk);
            if (rst = '1') then
                    acc_out <= (others => '0');     
            elsif (en = '1') then
                    acc_out <=  acc_in;
            end if;
        end process acc;

    P <= acc_out;

end Behavioral;
```

[image: Multiplication mistake]

Comment: Waveform added.

Comment: I don't remember so much about VHDL, but `product` should be updated asynchronously right? In that case the problem is not `acc`, but the actual multiplication...

Comment: Well, that's what this posts is about.

Comment: Yep, sorry, I was confused by the context...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you multiply 2 5-bit numbers (`A` and `B` are both `std_logic_vector(4 downto 0)`) don't you need 10 bits (not 9) to store it in (so `P` should be `std_logic_vector(9 downto 0)`? (31*31 = 961: needs 10 bits)

But also - [don't use `std_logic_arith`/`_unsigned`](https://parallelpoints.com/numbers-in-vhdl/).  Use `ieee.numeric_std` and then use the `unsigned` data type.

Comment: I am not allowed to change packages. Moreover I have to meet provided conventions to meet synthaseable code.
Regarding the problem,  the output vector length was the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Why are you not allowed to change packages?  Can you not at least get rid of std_logic_arith (assuming you are doing unsigned maths)?

Comment: If you are really synthesizing, then you may want to consider a simple pipelined vendor-specific core instead.

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco: or just stick a `*` in with a few pipeline registers afterwards and let the synth tool figure out where to put them - much more portable.